# Help with this sql syntax

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

```
SELECT [ID] + ' - ' + CAST([OfficeID] as char(5)) AS [ZoneID] , [Name] FROM [dbo].[ZoneByOffice] 
WHERE ([OfficeID] IN (@Office))
AND (('0003' in @Activity) OR ('0007' in @Activity))
ORDER BY [Name] ASC
```

this sql script will fail in retrieving the datasource, a popup will ask for the definitions of '@Activity' and '@Office', even though those Parameters exist.

But if I were to treat '@Activity' as a single non-array value, like so :

```
SELECT [ID] + ' - ' + CAST([OfficeID] as char(5)) AS [ZoneID] , [Name] FROM [dbo].[ZoneByOffice] 
WHERE ([OfficeID] IN (@Office))
AND ((@Activity ='0003') OR (@Activity = '0007'))
ORDER BY [Name] ASC
```

then it will not prompt for definitions, but on the report if I select multiple Acitivity items, it will report ',' commas in the syntax and fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If @Activity is a single value, then you can use

```
(@Activity IN ('0003', '0007'))
```

But if @Activity is a comma-separated list of values, you can't pass it as a single parameter anyway.  SQL parameters can never substitute for a list of values -- only **one single value**.  If the string you pass for the parameter looks like a list of numbers, it doesn't matter.  It's still just a single value, which happens to be a string of digits and commas.

You can try [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause/337817#337817), popularized on Stack Overflow by Joel Spolsky himself:

```
WHERE ',' + @Activity + ',' LIKE '%,' + '0003' + ',%'
   OR ',' + @Activity + ',' LIKE '%,' + '0007' + ',%'
```

But it performs terribly, because the leading wildcards in the patterns force a table-scan.

Comment: thanks for the educational trick, but I discovered all I had to do was bracket the @Activity like ('0003' in (@Activity)) in order for it to work >_<

Comment: Well don't expect that to work on any other brand of database.